# UE Replace In Files with Regular Expressions and the 'any characters' ( * ) character

Tags: ultraedit

I'm using UltraEdit's (on a Mac) **Find** and **Replace In Files** with regular expressions to clean up SQL Server code blocks in multiple files. And I am noticing that **Find in Files** outputs expected result, but **Replace In Files** does not make the replaces as expected.

For example, convert lower case `case-when-then` blocks to upper case `CASE-WHEN-THEN`:

[image: Screen shot of Replace in Files window with the search and replace string]

**FIND IN FILES**

`case*when*then` correctly finds this line:

**case when** a1c.optimum = 1 and ldl.optimum = 1 and sbp.optimum = 1 and dbp.optimum = 1 **then** 1 else 0 end optimum,

**REPLACE IN FILES**

`case*when*then` to `CASE*WHEN*THEN` results for the line above in following line with `when` and `then` not replaced as expected to upper case words:

**CASE*WHEN*THEN** 1 else 0 end optimum,

What is wrong on **Replace In Files**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously using the **UltraEdit regular expression** engine where `*` matches any character except [newline characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) **0** or more times.

You have to use a [tagged regular expression](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/tagged_expressions.html) to keep parts of found strings unmodified.

Search string: `case^(*^)when^(*^)then`

Replace string: `CASE^1WHEN^2THEN`

The same replace using **Unix** or **Perl regular expression** engine:

Search string: `case(.*)when(.*)then`

Replace string: `CASE\1WHEN\2THEN`

See [Perl regular expression using backreferences](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/perl-regular-expressions-backreferences.html) from [IDM Power Tips](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips.html) for an explanation.

By the way: Much better would be with **Perl regular expression** engine:

Search string: `\bcase\b(.*?)\bwhen\b(.*?)\bthen\b`

Replace string: `CASE\1WHEN\2THEN`

`\b` means word boundary and therefore `case`, `when` and `then` must be entire words and not just 3 strings which each could exist also anywhere within a word.